# html metadata for single-page React App

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags, single-page-application, react-js

I am adding html meta data to my single-page react web app for the purpose of search engine optimization. Some answers on related stack overflow posts suggested using react-helmet to manage the meta data of each route component.

If I do it in this way, how would the meta data in index.html affect the meta data of route components?

Should I remove the meta tags from index.html, given that I have a Home Component as the landing page and can set the meta data of the component using react-helmet?